# Comparing between two polygon class values

Tags: qgis, change-detection, hot-spot, geoda

I have one polygon shapefile with two fields that I would like to detect their difference.
the fields have the same class values: between 0-4:

This is the first layer:
[image]

and this is the second:
[image]

I would like to compare between those two. I thought that the base way would be using :

```
abs('field one'-'field two')
```

but i'm not sure if this is the best way.

My end goal is to create new map that shows the differnce of those two layers, and to be sure I know to explain it well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each polygon has data for both fields, and both are integers 0-4, perhaps you could construct a plot that has 3 different sorts of symbology:
1. where field 1 = field 2 (no change)
2. field2 > field 1 (increased significance)
3. field2< field1 (decreased significance)